# ko.applybindings not working on dynamic html element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm writing some code, where when the user clicks on the file upload button, upon success, add a new row to the table which includes a download button. This button will have a data-bind click handler attached to it.

I'm trying to apply knockoutbindings to a dynamic html row.  without any succcess. From my code, i'm receiving no error, but upon clicking the download button, nothing happens.

code

ViewModel

```
$(function () {

        // download section viewModel
        var viewModel = function () {
            self.downloadOrder = function (item, event) {
                var domElement = event.target;
                $.fileDownload('@Url.Action("test", "test")' + "?fileName=" + item.documentName + "&quoteNoEncrypted=" + item.quoteNoEncrypt, {

                    failCallback: function () {
                        $("<span style='position: absolute'> @TranslationService.Read("Waybill_Common_FileNoLongerExist", module, languageCode) </span>").insertAfter(domElement).fadeIn(1000, "linear", function () {
                            $(domElement).next().delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
                        });

                    }
                });
            };

        }
```

Bindings on initial document load

```
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("documentSection"));
        ko.applyBindings(headerViewModel, document.getElementById("dashBoardHeader"));
        ko.applyBindings(quoteVM, document.getElementById("viewRequest"));
```

upon success of upload add a row to the documents table and applybindings. 
Issue.

```
           $("#btncareerssubmimt").click(function () {
            $("#uploadDocumentForm").ajaxSubmit({
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, file) {
                        // insert new datafile row to the table
                        $("#supporting-documents-table >tbody:last").append('<tr id=' + file.DocumentId + '><td>' + file.Title + '</td>' + '<td>' +
                            file.UploadDate + '</td>' + '<td>' + '<input type="button" value="@TranslationService.Read("Waybill_Common_DownloadTitle", module, languageCode)" data-bind="click: function(data, event){downloadOrder({quoteNoEncrypt: "@Model.QuoteNoEncrypt", documentName:' +
                            file.Title + '}, event)}" />' + '</td></tr>');

                        // get new row id
                        var rowId = $("#supporting-documents-table tr:last").attr('id');

                        // add the download knockout handler to this new row

                        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById(rowId));

                    })
      }):
```

any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reapply bindings like:

```
var element = document.getElementById("documentSection");
ko.cleanNode(element);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, element);
```

But I don't suggest to do that as far as I remember that not supported very well (as it doesn't clear event handlers).

Proper way of doing that will be having `observableArray` of your supporting documents and than in view you need add logic to iterate thought that array and display your rows and on `success` you simply need to add new object to that `observableArray` and row will be added automatically. (nice example can be found [there](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vladimirs direction, the issue, was solved by using observable arrays.

I added a a uploadDocument function to the  existing viewModel

```
uploadDocument: function (documentList) {
        if (documentList != null) {
           _uploadButtonDisable(true)
              // start spinner  
            var target = document.getElementById('uploadMessage');           
            var spinner = new Spinner().spin(target);                                   

                        //show spinner
            $(target).val("").show();

            $("#uploadDocumentForm").ajaxSubmit({
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, file) {
                    // insert new datafile row to the table
                     documentList.push(file);
                     spinner.stop(spinner);
                     $("#uploadMessage").text('@TranslationService.Read("SSP_Common_Success_Text", "SSP", languageCode)').fadeIn(1000, "linear", function () {
                     $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                           $(this).text("");
                     });

                  });
                  _uploadButtonDisable(false)

                })

                },
                    error: function () {
                        spinner.stop(spinner);
                                $("#uploadMessage").text('@TranslationService.Read("SSP_Server_Error_UI_Text", "SSP", languageCode)').fadeIn(1000, "linear", function () {
                                    $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut("slow", function () {
                                        $(this).text("");
                                    });

                                });
                                _uploadButtonDisable(false)
                                //input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));

                            }
                        });
                        var input = $("#choose-file");

                    }
                }
```

Bind the viewModel.

```
           var jsonModel = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))';
           var mvcwModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonModel);
           mvcwModel.viewModel = viewModel;

           ko.applyBindings(mvcwModel, document.getElementById("viewRequest"));
```

attach uploadDocument to uploadButton

```
<tr>
   <td>
  <th><input type="button" value="@TranslationService.Read("Waybill_OrderDisplay_UploadSubmit", module, languageCode)" id="btncareerssubmimt" class=" floatRight" data-bind="disable: viewModel.uploadButtonDisable, click: function(){ viewModel.uploadDocument($root.Documents);}" /></th>
   </td>
</tr>
```